# Work in gravitational field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, work

I was doing a test a few days ago and there was a fairly simple task involving gravity basics. The task asks me to calculate the work done by moving an Earth's artificial satellite from a stationary orbit at $2R$ to a stationary orbit at $3R$, supposing we know the mass of Earth, the mass of the satellite and gravitational constant.

My way: Simple take the integral as follows :

$$A = Fds = \int_{2R}^{3R} \frac{\gamma Mm}{r^2}dr = \frac{\gamma Mm}{6R}$$
However, the test results show that this solution is incorrect and that the correct solution is half of mine solution i.e. $\frac{\gamma Mm}{12R}$. I tried getting this solution but I can't seem to get it.

Can someone explain the fallacy in my methods?

Comment: The kinetic energy will change as well.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't do anything wrong, just incomplete.  As @Sebastian alluded to, the work will be

$$W=E_{3R}-E_{2R}=T_{3R}+V_{3R}-T_{2R}-V_{2R}$$

where the subscript denotes orbital position.  You already found the $V_{3R}-V_{2R}$ term, now just use the centripetal motion formula

$$\frac{mv^2}{r}=\frac{\gamma Mm}{r^2}$$

to find the difference in kinetic energy $T_{3R}-T_{2R}$.